# Selenium element.click() does not work

Tags: pdf, selenium, download

Hello: I am using Selenium/Java to grab a PDF from a website.  The website does not generate them in advance, but only after I clink on a link. When I do, the web server goes away for a few minutes, and then comes back with the content.

I'm using Firefox, and its built-in PDF viewer.  When I click on the download link from the main browser window, it opens another window to receive the PDF content.  In a few minutes the child window is filled with the PDF content, and all I need to do is click a *download* button on the Firefox toolbar, and then press a *Save* button on the confimration dialog. I have done both of these things, successfully, sometimes.

My problem, *sometimes* occurs when I execute the code to click on the child window's *download* button...

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("download"));

element.click();

Sometimes, it just doesn't work.  The statement:

driver.findElement(By.id("download"))

...never throws an exception, so it appears to *always* be successful.  Yet, the subsequent element.click() will often not produce the expected results.

I've thrown about 100 darts at this problem, but I can't seem to find one that produces consistent results.  I've tried introducing delays, calling findElement several times, trying to use the driver on the child window in ways to confirm its connection to that window (all with positive return values), but nothing seems to help make element.click() on the darn download link successfull.

I have found Selenium to be a rock-solid solution, especially when working through the primary window...it never misses a beat, and I'm really quite impressed about that behavior.  This is my first Selenium project, and I hoping someone that has used it a bit more, might have a suggestion for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this question without additional information about how the child window is populated. If the child window is using javascript to add the button to the page and define its behavior (which is likely), then the element could be actually present on the page when you look for it (i.e. no error will be thrown), but it might not be active yet or prepared to be clicked.

It might be a good idea to look at the element definition in the source for the child page to get a better idea of how the button is coded. If you have access to the web developers who designed/implemented the button even better. If you can wait to perform the click action until the button is in the desired state, this should solve the problem.

Additionally if the page is coded using a dynamic framework like Angular, you might be better off using [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) for testing, which is based off of Selenium, but which is aware of updates in the view as they are occurring.

Comment: Your secondary question as an answer might be best asked as another question. If you create a new question you will get more directed answers for it. Feel free to link it to me here in the comments to my answer and I will respond with an answer for you. :)